# Stopping SignalR-connection is slow

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Stoping SignalR connection of Javascript client is slow (around 30 seconds).

I use SignalR, version 2.0.1 (but problem reproduced in 2.0.0 ) for webchat integrated to ASP.NET site. I have one .NET SignalR client(for other reason) and a lot of JS clients (chat clients). My test case is very simple. I want to disable chat on ASP.NET page. For this reason I try to stop SignalR connection using next code:

```
$.connection.hub.stop();
```

But onDisconnected method (on hub) was calling only after 30 seconds. I suppose that connection was stopped by disconnect timeout but not by Javascript code. I use LongPolling transpot by default.

```
var initObject = { transport: ["longPolling", "webSockets", "foreverFrame", "serverSentEvents"] };
$.connection.hub.start(initObject).done(function () {
    ...
}
```

Problem reproduce in last versions of Google Chrome but works fine in IE and Mozilla. What reason of so strange behaviour of SignalR and how can I avoid it?

Comment: For reference : https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2653

Comment: @Jason Evans, thanks for reference, but I think that it is not my case, because my problem related with Javascript-clients, (not .NET clients).

Comment: Is it that slow even when you only have 1-2 clients?

Comment: @Abhishek Nanda, yes.

Comment: Seems to me like stop() probably isn't doing its job then. If you're getting the 30 second timeout it means that the connection isn't being killed by you calling stop. 

Do you have a repro for this problem?

Comment: @dfowler, I can't give you project with problem because it is very complex part of site integrated to other parts but I can collect any logs which you want. Yes you right, connection isn't being killed by stop calling because I can send data after stop calling. Problem is seen only with longPolling and Google Chrome.

Comment: @dfowler, I found that problem is not seen when .NET client doesn't connect to the hub. So I can suppose that reproduction case is next: 1). Run ASP.NET 4.5 (.NET 4.5) WebForms site on IIS7/IIS8 with SignalR(2.0.1) Hub. 2). First run .NET client (.NET 4.5) and connect to the hub. 3) Then run JS client on Google Chrome with LongPolling transport and connect to the hub. 4) Try to disconnect using $.connection.hub.stop() call.

Comment: File an issue on github with the specific repro steps.

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2816

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by updating SignalR version to the 2.0.3.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this issue just use `conn.Stop(new TimeSpan(0))` to kill the connection instantly.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.disconnect();
conn.stop();
hub.subscribe(null);
conn = null;
hub= null;
```

try this and let me know if it works.It works in android though.